# Why it is occuring KeyError: 'main' and how to solve it

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am having keyerror: 'main'. I have searched many sites, but still can't find any satisfactory answer to solve this error. I would really appreciate if someone can give me some pointers. Thanks in advance.

I have tried solving this by adding a function on the *init*.py which is suggested by a site. But it still didn't work.
https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/t/error-on-sys-modules/6431/2

code: view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from .models import City


def index(request):
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=imperial&appid=MYKey'
    cities = City.objects.all()  # return all the cities in the database
    city = 'Dhaka'
    # request the API data and convert the JSON to Python data types
    city_weather = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()

    weather_data = []

    for city in cities:

        # request the API data and convert the JSON to Python data types
        city_weather = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()

        weather_app = {
            'city': city,
            'temperature': city_weather['main']['temp'],
            'description': city_weather['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon': city_weather['weather'][0]['icon']
        }

        # add the data for the current city into our list
        weather_data.append(weather_app)

    #context = {'weather' : weather_app}
    context = {'weather_data': weather_data}

    # returns the index.html template
    return render(request, 'weather_app/index.html')
```

terminal:

```
(env) acer@acer-Aspire-V3-472P:~/DjangoProject/Weather$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 03, 2019 - 06:48:01
Django version 2.2, using settings 'Weather.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/acer/DjangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/acer/DjangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/acer/DjangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/acer/DjangoProject/Weather/weather_app/views.py", line 30, in index
    'temperature': city_weather['main']['temp'],
KeyError: 'main'
[03/May/2019 06:48:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 68977
```

Comment: How does your `City` model look like? Looks to me that the API request is failing and that might be due to how the API url is formatted when iterating over cities.

Answer (score 1):

You don't check that the data for the specific city is found. You loop through all cities in your database, and try to get the weather for each one; but you don't check that the result is actually returned. You should do:

```
for city in cities:
    response = requests.get(url.format(city))
    if response.status_code == 404:
        continue
    city_weather = response.json()
```

Also, you should check that you are formatting your URL properly. As it stands, you are inserting your City object directly into the URL - this will only work if you have defined a `__str__` method that returns only the city name. It would be better to use the name directly:

```
response = requests.get(url.format(city.name))   # or whatever the name field is
```

Comment: thanks Daniel Roseman. It helped a lot. But sadly now I am getting Typeerror, I don't know how should I solve it. I'm novice in python

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure. I have a suggestion. You may check the `city_weather`data (using print())before making `weather_app` to see if the key`'main'`is really in `city_weather`, maybe the key happened not to be in the data.